Working on a wordpress site, trying to add a custom jquery script to change the main logo image to a different one 100px after scrolling down
Working on a wordpress site, trying to add a custom jquery script to change the main logo image to a different one 100px after scrolling down. This is what i got so far, it does not change the image to the isotype after 100px of scrolling down, but according to the inspector the code is there. I tried both of these scripts, since WP has an issue when using the $ in jQuery scripts. Neither worked.


(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
     
      if($(this).scrollTop() > 100){
        
        $('#logo').attr('src', 'http://www.haciendamontezuma.workbycardinal.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/iso.png');
      } else {
       
        $('#logo').attr('src', 'https://www.haciendamontezuma.workbycardinal.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/logo-fff.png');
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>





jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    // Check if user scrolled more than 100px
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      // Change the logo source to the new one
      jQuery('#logo').attr('src', 'http://www.haciendamontezuma.workbycardinal.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/iso.png');
    } else {
      // If user scrolls back up, revert to original logo
      jQuery('#logo').attr('src', 'https://www.haciendamontezuma.workbycardinal.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/logo-fff.png');
    }
  });
});




Your code seems to work, the image changes when you scroll

"Does not work" is not a useful problem description. What have you done so far to try and debug the issue? // The site appears to have an automatic redirect from HTTP to HTTPS in place - so I would use HTTPS URLs for the images as well, otherwise you risk the browser refusing to load them, because they are insecure content on a secure page.

Yes both of you are right but the code is not working, see first the image seems to change because the theme has a light/dark feature where you can upload a second logo, so rows tagged dark will use the dark logo and change the color of the text to a specified dark color, if youre seeing the logo change its cache, i removed the second logo, "does not work" what i mean is the logo is not changing, the logo i want past 100px is the isotype, so the full logo < 100, >100 from top just the whitle little isotype. If you delete cache you'll see now i only have the original complete white logo.

Wordpress can be quirky with jquery, i was thinking maybe to eliminate the first function, and change the the $ after the ready function, for jQuery, but that did not help either
